# Numbering the Tables in Mathematica and Grid

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, nested-lists

I am new to Mathematica. I will try to do my best to write it effectively.

I have two questions:

**Q1:** 
I have three tables which give me values as {x1,y1,z1} ,{x2,y2,z2}...The code is given below:

```
    Table[Table[Table[ {xcord, ycord, zcord},  
                       {xcord, 0, 50, 5}],  
                       {ycord, 0, 50,5}],   
                       {zcord, 50, 150, 10}]
```

Now I need an output like this

```
{1,x1,y1,z1}

{2,x2,y2,z2}

{3,x3,y3,z3}

.
.
{n,xn,yn,zn}
```

There are two problems with this.

First, I get my results formatted as something like this {x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}  ....  {xn,yn,zn}, but I want it formatted in this way:

```
 {x1,y1,z1}

 {x2,y2,z2}

 {x3,y3,z3}

 .
 .
 {xn,yn,zn}
```

Second, I can't number each set of elements adding the numbers in front of each set of elements like

```
{1,x1,y1,z1}

{2,x2,y2,z2}

{3,x3,y3,z3}

.
.
{n,xn,yn,zn}
```

I tried to make separate tables for each set of co-ordinates and number these corresponding to each set of the co-ordinates. Then I tried to get each of them in separate columns and join them but still I haven't been successful.

**Q2:**
I would like to separate the values obtained from the tables above into a grid system like the one below. Something like how we all do in Excel where all values reside in a separate cells.

```
                 Number          X values  Y Values  Z values
                     1            x1        y1       z1
                     2            x2        y2       z2
                     .
                     .
                     n            xn        yn        zn
```

Comment: Incidentally, you don't have to nest [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html) like that. It accepts multiple iterators, i.e. `Table[Table[ i + j, {j, 10}],{i,10}]` is equivalent to `Table[ i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]`. Note the order of the iterators is reversed.

Comment: Thanks @rcollyer for letting me know an alternative way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
i = 0; t2 = 
 Grid[Join[{{"Number", "X Values", "Y Values", "Z Values"}}, 
   Flatten[Table[{++i, xcord, ycord, zcord}, 
                              {xcord, 0, 50, 5}, 
                              {ycord, 0, 50, 5}, 
                              {zcord, 50, 150, 10}], 2]], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

The element numbers are added by two alternative methods, giving c and d.

```
a = Table[Table[Table[{xcord, ycord, zcord}, {xcord, 0, 50, 5}],
    {ycord, 0, 50, 5}], {zcord, 50, 150, 10}];
b = Flatten[a, 2];
c = MapIndexed[Flatten[{First[#2], #1}] &, b];
d = Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[b], Range[Length[b]]]];
Print[Row[{"c==d? ", c == d}]]
TableForm[Append[Take[c, 5], Table[".", {4}]],
 TableHeadings -> {None,
   {"Number", "X Values", "Y Values", "Z Values"}}]
```

c==d? True

Number  X Values    Y Values    Z Values

1   0   0   50

2   5   0   50

3   10  0   50

4   15  0   50

5   20  0   50

.   .   .   .